# AngularJS synchronisation between $scope and $localStorage

Tags: angularjs

Slightly new to AngularJS so please bear with me.

I'm trying to implement ngStorage but had a doubt. If I assign something like this:

```
$scope.$storage = $localStorage.default({
var: 'foo'
});
```

And then if `$scope.storage.var` is changed when an AJAX call is  made, does it also change the value of `$localStorage.var` or do I have to manually re-assign it?

If I do have to manually re-assign it, what's the best way to do so among the options below? (Please do let me know if there's any other way to do it)

1. `$localStorage.var = 'foo2'`;
2. `$localStorage.$reset({
   var : 'foo2'
   });`
3. `delete $localStorage.var` followed by `$localStorage.var = 'foo2'`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont feel it will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used the third option and it seemed to work correctly. That is:

`delete $localStorage.var;
$localStorage.var = 'foo2';`